# Replacing words in a file

Tags: python

It does work but it doesn't replace the letters.
First I open one file, and write the content to another. And then to the second file I replace some specific letters, but it doesn't work, An
any idea?
The code:

```
def  copy_file():

    f=open("cartas.txt","r")
    g=open("copiar.txt","r+")
    g.writelines(f)
    f.close()

    for line in g:
       line = line.replace("s","ch")
       g.write(line) 
    g.close()

copy_file()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over the lines in `g` and also write the modified lines to `g`. And before that you actually copy the contents from `f` into `g`.

What you should be doing is iterating over the lines of `f` and write them to `g` while converting them directly:

```
f = open('cartas.txt', 'r')
g = open('copiar.txt', 'r+')

for line in f:
    line = line.replace('s', 'ch')
    g.write(line)

f.close()
g.close()
```

Comment: why would you not just do a global replace and write the whole thing ... there is no need to go line by line

Comment: @JoranBeasley The OP implicitly is telling that she wants to "replace some specific letters". That means she might be wanting to replace more than one pattern per line.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Two reasons: First, the actual replacement could be more complicated, and dependant on the lines, and second, to not put all the content into the memory at once.

Answer (score 1):

After you call `g.writelines(f)`, the read pointer for `g` is at the end of the file, so the `for line in g:` afterwards has nothing to iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

This Python example will perform the replacement you need, because replace is global you do not need to replace line by line:

```
f = open("cartas.txt","r")
g = open("copiar.txt","w")
g.write(f.read().replace('s','ch'))
g.close()
f.close()
```